# A word for "applied immediately following"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word or phrase, - noun or adjective, to describe an action/activity that's applied immediately following another action/activity, rather than in conjunction with the first operation. Let's call these actions/activities "frobbing" and "barring". So I want to refer to "barring right after frobbing" rather than "frobbing together with barring".

I was thinking of "compounded barring" or "aposteriori barring", but did not quite like those.

**Edit:** It is necessary that the phrase or word not refer to the frobbing, as I want to use the same phrase/word for multiple, different, initial actions (frobbing, bazzing, quuxing etc.)

Comment: **"post-frob barring?"**

Comment: @MaxWilliams: This won't do for two reasons. First, because of being frob-specific (see edit). Second, because this doesn't seem to communicate well enough that it's _immediately_ after the frobbing, with no gap in-between. e.g. a post-mortem examination of a body can happen hours or even more after the actual death.

Comment: Can you add some example sentences please?

Comment: Why not just say 'immediate'? That seems to be exactly what you're after.

Comment: Does "subsequent" not work?  Or does that not convey the immediacy?

Comment: Technically "tandem" works, but the most common usage is in regards to things working in conjunction instead of one after another, so it would fail the single-word request.

Comment: In boxing, the [“old one-two {combo/punch}”](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/one-two) describes a combination of two distinct punches, the second of which follows immediately after the first, with the adjective “following” often being used to describe the second blow: [“A {frob} or two, with a **following** right {bar} …”](https://books.google.com/books?id=NlB5Zhz9yRoC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%22a+following+right+cross%22&source=bl&ots=D2_Lv_YDZn&sig=l4totU96-QTdC7sxlwCj1P__h2E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFjYSv-evNAhXFWz4KHQk-ATYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20following%20right%20cross%22&f=false).

Comment: Why ... not ... just ... use ... words???

Comment: @Ste: No, [I think it doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequent_Nuremberg_trials)

Comment: @PapaPoule: Well, that's a gerund and I need to use it with another gerund: "A following barring"? I don't know...

Comment: What's wrong with "the immediately following action" of just "the following action". You've asked for "a word or phrase, - noun or adjective" - and there you have a phrase with an adjective & a noun & optionally and adverb!

Comment: @ChristopherD.: Can you link somewhere suggesting this used of "tandem"?

Comment: @TrevorD: That doesn't have the connotation of being applied, like "compounded" (think: "Compounded interest" - except the application of the second action is not necessarily a compounding).

Comment: Because I didn't know what you specifically mean by "applied" - I assume you mean something like applying a lotion to the skin. You have previously been asked (3 hours ago) for some example sentences - but have not supplied any!  So we are left guessing what you want.  Voting to close for "unclear what you're asking."

Comment: "Utilizing a tandemed process of frobbing then barring precluded the need for Quality Assurance to audit the frobbing work in process." The common idiom is "in tandem" which relates to concurrent processes in usage. So you need to provide context that you are using "tandem" to mean one before the other, instead of meaning synchronized, hence the "frobbing *then* barring."

Comment: You can abuse *postjacent* to indicate something is after something else. But its usual usage is spatial, not temporal.

Answer (score 1):

The best wording depends on the precise situation because there are many context-specific words. But here are a few possibilities:

- The consecutive frobbing and barring.
- He frobbed then quickly barred.
- He went through the motions of frobbing then barring.